# Sql query to select from 1 hour ago?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this query but I want to change the date to delete everything that is from more than 1 hour ago based on the server time (or if not possible by server time by post date). How do I do that?

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts
 WHERE post_date < '2008-06-06 19:18:00' 
   AND post_status = 'publish'
```

Answer (score 108):

Use:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts
 WHERE post_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL '1' HOUR)
   AND post_status = 'publish'
```

Reference:

- [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)
- [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

Answer (score 39):

Or even simpler:

```
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```

So the query becomes:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts
 WHERE post_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
   AND post_status = 'publish'
```

Comment: In some RDBSs the time should be in single quotation like: `'1 Hour'`

Answer (score 0):

Subdate function works too!

```
SELECT subdate(current_timestamp, interval 1 hour)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE from  table where date_add < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```

to see the time run this sql :

```
select NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR as s1 , NOW() as s2;
```