# PHP + MySql Cron Job, remove rows that are over 1 hour old

Tags: php, mysql, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sql query to select from 1 hour ago?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451385/sql-query-to-select-from-1-hour-ago)

my current cron job script removes all rows from database which is not good if user wants to reset password at that time when cronjob runs, how I can check with mysql when row is added to database and that way remove only rows that are been there more than 1 hour?

My cron_reset.php

```
<?php
require_once('mysql_config.php');
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) 
{
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) 
{
    die("Unable to select database");
}


function clean($str) 
{
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
    {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

$password = clean($_GET['password']);
if($password != $cron_password)
{
    die('Access Denied');
}
else
{
    $qry = "DELETE FROM cron_reset";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    if($result) 
    {
        die('Success');
    }
    else 
    {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

This is that line which adds email + reset code to database

```
            $qry = "INSERT INTO cron_reset(email, code) VALUES('$email','$code')";
            $result = @mysql_query($qry);
```

Comment: Cue the obligatory "don't use the `mysql_` functions" comment.

Comment: Does the table have any sort of timestamp column? That is a mandatory requirement  for timed deletions.

Comment: I added now, but I have no idea how to check if its added more than 1 hour ago.

Comment: @Lanibox You added a timestamp column?

Comment: `DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE timestamp_column <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`

Answer (score 1):

In your DB schema, you will have to add a new column to store the time of the demand (eg ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and add a where clause in your query (WHERE ts < NOW()- INTERVAL 1 HOUR)

Comment: You should probably mark it as correct then :) People may miss the interest in looking for a solution if you haven't marked a correct one, and also it rewards the account answering..