# MySQL - Select rows where 1 hour before datetime column

Tags: mysql

I have these rows

```
id |      start_time      |
1  |  2018-06-15 02:00:00 |
2  |  2018-06-15 02:45:00 |
3  |  2018-06-15 03:45:00 |
```

I want to select rows that are 1 hour before the start_time.  So if the time is `2018-06-15 01:00:00` then the first row should be returned.

How do i do this?  I've tried below but i don't know how to subtract 1 hour from `start_time`.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H') <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H');
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451385/sql-query-to-select-from-1-hour-ago

Comment: What you are saying is one hour after (in your example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To subtract hours ,use date_sub function
In your case

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H'), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Comment: do i need a where clause to use with this?

Comment: yes like this-WHERE DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H'), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H');